# Как разбить цифру в числа

Tags: javascript

Есть число 8 на входе, нужно чтобы на выходе было 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8, пробовал через цикл не получилось

Comment: Приведите код вашей не удачной реализации? Что значит разбить на числа? На выходе должна быть строка или массив элементов?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
console.log([...Array(8)].map((e, i) => i + 1).join(','))
```

Либо чтобы не создавать массив:

```js
let str = ''
for (let i = 0; i < 8; i++) str += (i + 1) + ','
console.log(str.slice(0, str.length - 1))
```